# Apache Tika - all files from directory listed in ArrayList

Tags: apache-tika

i need to lists all files with selected type by apache's Tika tool, my target is just to save all .doc, .docx etc files from selected directory to for example ArrayList

Comment: OK, and what have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Where's your code?

Comment: to be honest i only read some documentation of Tika, and that's all